# Quantifying fit of a non-linear model

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, predictive-models, modeling

I have developed a non-linear model that utilizes 0-fitting parameters (all my inputs can be/are determined experimentally). As of now I have performed propagation of error and a GSA using Sobol indices, but I would like to have a better measure of how well it concurs with my experiments.

Is it possible to compare the bootstrapped model averages with the experimental averages for the entire time series using a statistical test, rather than just the RMSE or MSE?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If there are no parameters, there is nothing to test.  Thus, it sounds like you need some way of comparing some abstract model results to some abstract experiment.  That doesn't give us anything to go on to help you out.  Could you supply some relevant details?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Essentially, I have a model for a particular system that takes 8 different measurable inputs, the outputs of which are also measurable by experiment. Ideally, I would like to compare the calculated outputs from the model with my actual experimental results from the system in a more rigorous way than a visual comparison. The issue I am having is since all of the model inputs for a particular experimental condition are determined already, I have no adjustable parameters that I am using to fit my model to my data, the parameters are already defined by the experiment.

Comment: Do the outputs vary or not?  If they don't vary, there isn't much you can do.  If they do vary, then *how*?  What statistical description of their variation can you provide?

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, not only as comments. Comments are often seen only by a few and can be deleted!